# Separate a column into two columns based on nth occurrence of delimiter

Tags: r

Using R, what do I need to do to split col4 of TABLEA below into col4a and col4b of TABLEB below?  I can't figure out how to get this to work, when there might not always be a 3rd "-" to split on.

TABLEA:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| data | data | data | hippo-11-trx-2021 |
| data | data | data | goose-17-plt-2017 |
| data | data | data | monkey-01-mno |
| data | data | data | zebra-99-451-2019 |

TABLEB:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4a | col4b |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| data | data | data | hippo-11-trx | 2021 |
| data | data | data | goose-17-plt | 2017 |
| data | data | data | monkey-01-mno | NA |
| data | data | data | zebra-99-451 | 2019 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tidyr`'s `extract` :

```
result <- tidyr::extract(df, col4, c('col4a', 'col4b'), 
                             '(\\w+-\\w+-\\w+)-?(\\d+)?$', convert = TRUE)
result

#    col1 col2 col3         col4a col4b
#1   data data data  hippo-11-trx  2021
#2   data data data  goose-17-plt  2017
#3   data data data monkey-01-mno    NA
#4   data data data  zebra-99-451  2019
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(col1 = c("  data", "  data", "  data", "  data"
), col2 = c("data", "data", "data", "data"), col3 = c("data", 
"data", "data", "data"), col4 = c("hippo-11-trx-2021", "goose-17-plt-2017", 
"monkey-01-mno", "zebra-99-451-2019")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a stepwise solution:

```
#load string package
library(stringr)
```

Then create col 4b based on whether col4 ends with an hyphen and 4 digit number (using grepl() and str_extract):

```
ifelse(grepl('.*-[[:digit:]]{4}$', df$col4)==TRUE, df$col4b<-str_extract(df$col4, '[[:digit:]]{4}$'), NA)
```

Then remove the corresponding number strings from col4 using str_remove():

```
df$col4<-str_remove(string=df$col4, pattern='-[[:digit:]]{4}$')
```

Finally, rename col4 as col4a

```
names(df)[names(df)=='col4']<-'col4a'
```

```
> df
    col1 col2 col3         col4a col4b
1   data data data  hippo-11-trx  2021
2   data data data  goose-17-plt  2017
3   data data data monkey-01-mno  <NA>
4   data data data  zebra-99-451  2019
```